# Find the point in a point cloud that is furthest in a given direction

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a point cloud represented as an (unsorted) array of `Vector3` in *Unity*. In addition, I have a direction vector.

What is the best (most efficient) way to find the point that is furthest in the given direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just compute the dot product and take the largest. This "projects" the point onto the direction.

```
myPoints.MaxBy(p => Vector3.Dot(p, myDirection));
```

Comment: Wouldn't you additionally need a start point? As I understand we do not want to start from the world center but the question is rather like - starting from a given 3D position, looking into a given direction, which is the furthest point? I think somewhat like `var furthest = myPoints.MaxBy(p => Vector3.Dot(p - startPos, myDirection));`

Comment: @derHugo You do not *need* a start point. If you have a startpoint you would simply subtract it from each point: `p - startPoint`. But this gives the point furthest in a given line/ray rather than a direction.

Comment: I mean taking into account a direction alone makes no sense .. a position vector always has a start point - for now (tbf based on OP's question it is pretty unclear) you just assumed the world origin to be that start point ;)

Comment: @derHugo I think naming conventions are important. A "position" and a "direction" are different things, even if both are represented with a "vector". A position does not have a "start point", it is defined based on the origin for whatever coordinate system it uses. If any position/direction uses different coordinate systems you need to do some transformation, any comparisons are only valid in the same coordinate system. Using a direction alone *may* make sense, it would depend on the coordinate system and use case.